# How to restrict any tag for filtering questions?

Tags: support, bug, tags, search

Suppose I want to see all questions tagged with `select2` but not tagged with `angularjs`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [following query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select2%20not%20angularjs?mode=all) in the search box:

```
[select2] -[angularjs]
```

This is also mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching):

> To exclude results from a tag, term or phrase, prefix it with `-` in your query

EDIT: this only seems to work certain circumstances - as an anonymous user the result is just `[select2]` - the tag exclusion seems to be ignored. As @Stijn points out, it works as well under the old navigation. Here are two screenshots with network traffic, it might be helpful finding the cause of this bug:

[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry its not working.

Comment: @Drone that could have something to do with the new navigation - as an anonymous user it isn't working for me either.

Comment: It works fine for me with the old navigation *when logged in*. [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/l1YLrzs.png)